# LTE value RSRP, RSRQ in Android

Tags: android, lte

Is there anyway to get LTE value RSRP, RSRQ???
I thought that we can get the value from using CellSignalStrengthLte.
But the class Added in API level 17. So we can't install it to real device.

Is there anyway to get the value with ICS device?

And

```
Creator<CellSignalStrengthLte> lte_signal = new Creator<CellSignalStrengthLte>() {

    CellSignalStrengthLte lte_signal;

    @Override
    public CellSignalStrengthLte[] newArray(int size) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lte_rsrq = lte_signal.getDbm();
        textOut.append(String.format("RSRP(LTE):%s", lte_rsrq));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CellSignalStrengthLte createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
};
```

Is this right structure to get the value of LTE?

Please let me know....!!!
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the possibly naive question, but what does the "Creator<>" syntax mean in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to Android documentation for cellSignalStrengthGsm

```
                CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
                CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
                cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```